# How to print a file in cocoa application depending upon its mime type?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsprintoperation, nsprintinfo

I am working on file manager. I have stored their local urls in my core data. I have file and folder, but I want to print png, jpeg, docx and pdf from my application. 
Let's suppose I have a print button in my application and every file, how can I print that?

Answer (score 0):

use launch services LSOpenFromURLSpec as described [in the reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-BABBJHID). pass [kLSLaunchAndPrint as launch option](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/LSLaunchFlags) in the specs array.

Comment: @HASSAN MASOOD  did this answer help you? if yes, would you like to accept it?